# Android GridLayout single child does not consider weight while using columnCount

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to create a grid with 2 columns and infinite rows (added programatically), with 2+ childs it works perfectly, the childs take half width normally, but when i a add a single child it does not take half width, instead it fills parent..

**IMPORTANT NOTE: The content is dynamic, can have a single element or N, so it need to works with single element and with multiple elements**

This is what i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:orientation="horizontal"
    app:columnCount="2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:text="This is a text that need to have width as 50% screen size "/>
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout >
```

This is the result of the code above:
[image]

When i add a new TextView with the same properties as one above:
[image]

And this is the result i wants to have adding a single textview:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use weights and do this in a LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="This is a text that needs to have width as 50% of screen size"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It would look like this.

[image]

**EDIT**

If you want two columns and then to be able to add however many textviews (or any other layouts) in rows you want then you can separate the layout into two LinearLayouts like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="2">

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/leftLayout"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/rightLayout"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

To add a textview to a column you can do it programmatically like this.

```
leftView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.leftView);
TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

textView.setText("testDynamic textView");
leftView.addView(textView);
```

Comment: i added a important note in the question, this workaround i need to manage by hand if the list contains odd or even elements

Comment: I don't understand. If says two columns, what would you need to add dynamically?

Comment: @YuriHeupa I edited my answer to see if that's what you meant by dynamically.